# C++/MFC - Preventing a hanging child (ActiveX) control from freezing the whole UI?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, activex, freeze

I'm currently playing around with Microsofts WebBrowser ActiveX control and I noticed that I can freeze my whole program by loading a web page that crashes the embedded IE.
So I wondered if there's any way to prevent the whole programm from freezing?

I already tried:
- To Create a new CWinThread creating/handling the Control --> Same result
- To Create a new Dialog from this Thread creating/handling the Control --> Same result

The Problem seems to be deep in the message system, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone tell me if it is is even possible to prevent the whole UI/Dialog from freezing and what causes this problem?

(I already searched the web but I couldn't find any real solution)

Thanx, Gary

PS: The only way that currently works for me is to create a new child process loading/handling the control. I can modifiy it so that it looks like a child window of my main dialog but this takes the ability from me to access the control directly from my main dialog code.

**EDIT:**

**Okay I found a solution that satisfies me. I'm creating a placeholder window in the main application and start a new child process containing the actual control. I delegate all window move/size/etc. messages to the child process so that it can reposition/react.
It was important not to create the new process as a WS_CHILD object from my main application because that way it would still freeze it.
I'm sharing information through a memory map with the process and comunicate using custom user messages.
I Hoped it would be easier...**

Comment: If you create a new thread, that won't protect the rest of the app if the code in the thread crashes. You probably have an unhandled exception, and that's why the program crashes. You must make sure you catch and handle everything. And if you have hardware exceptions (division by 0, access invalid memory) you can catch and handle them with Structured Exception Handling (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex area. Preventing problems in one UI object causing problems in directly-releated parent UI object is something that has consumed a lot of time for the browser folks, who've attempted to ensure that one tab cannot crash another. I think it's fair to say that this is rocket science, and too large a topic to describe here.

You've picked a good starting point (separate the frame into a new process). Something else you will want to learn about is thread input queues and AttachThreadInput (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956(VS.85).aspx). Raymond has some content on this too; including part of PDC talk http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/01/8795860.aspx.

Extra advice: An alternative here might be to simply disallow loading AX controls in your browser control if you don't need them. And if yo do need them and are building a very general browsing replacement, you should anticipate lots of work to replicate the stability you'll find in the main browsers.